# Why do some questions show with a yellow background?

Tags: support, user-interface

I suspect I'm missing something really obvious (and might have to delete this question in embarrassment!).

I can't see the reason why some questions have a yellow background (e.g. see below from current home page).

[image: screenshot showing question with yellow background]

What have I missed? Thanks!

Comment: Please don't delete the question - it might be helpful to others! 

Comment: The yellow one has an eye in it! The others don't have the eye.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Watched Tags

I have wondered about this for years.

A couple of days ago I noticed that these yellowish orange questions seem to coincide with my **Watched Tags**.

Let us know if this is true for you also.

Comment: Yeah, there should be a cross-over with watched tags (eye icon) and yellow background.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The funny thing is, I had no idea I was watching a tag ... for some reason I was watching 'permissions' - must have been a phantom click - so I've un-watched it and the yellow has gone. Mystery solved, thanks!